# Unable to get CPM data from Youtube Analytics account

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I'm unable to get CPM data from my Youtube reports:

I'm getting:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Forbidden",
"errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't even know where to begin to debug this, and I haven't found anything online.

I'm just trying to curl the endpoint, mirroring this: [HERE](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?endDate=2014-06-30&ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&metrics=views%252Ccomments%252Clikes%252Cdislikes%252CestimatedMinutesWatched%252CaverageViewDuration%252Ccpm&startDate=2014-05-01&_h=2&)

Notice that once you finish the oauth process, User will see
"You do not have permission to execute this method." and the 403

Also, Notice if you remove 'CPM' from the list of metrics, this will work.

---

Example:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer _____access_token____" -e "https://developers.google.com" https://content-youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports\?endDate\=2014-06-30\&ids\=channel%3D%3DMINE\&metrics\=cpm\&startDate\=2014-05-01\&key\=_____api_key____
```

I'm getting the refresh token via:

```
<script>
var auth2;
var SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly', 
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
  ] ;

function initClient() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    'clientId': 'my-client-id',
    'scope': SCOPE.join(' '),
    'prompt': 'consent',
  })
}

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load('auth2', initClient);
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

the access token I'm using is from the refresh token via:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id={my_client_id}&client_secret={my_client_secret}&refresh_token={my_refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

and I'm getting:

```
{
 "access_token": "ya29.GlvyBZVPpC.....",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly",
 "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUz...."
}
```

I don't believe it's an issue with my scopes as I am not getting a 403 like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code we cant debug what we cant see

Comment: @DaImTo did you need more information for this ticket?

Comment: please include your authentication code as well sounds like you are using the wrong scope

Comment: @DaImTo I appreciate the help. I'm really blocked on this one. I don't believe it's an issue with the scopes, but if there's any more info I can provide, let me know.

Comment: again please include you authentication code how are you getting the refresh token.  the error means you don't have permission to do what you are trying to do.  either the user dosent have access or you are using the wrong scope

Comment: @DaImTo I want to refocus the issue on https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v2/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?endDate=2014-06-30&ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&metrics=views%252Ccomments%252Clikes%252Cdislikes%252CestimatedMinutesWatched%252CaverageViewDuration%252Ccpm&startDate=2014-05-01&_h=2&. I believe you're saying the scopes on the developer page was insufficient to get cost data (such as cpm) and if so, what recourse do i have for that data. I'm testing with a new gmail account without videos so I'm expecting to get 0s in my 200 rather than a 403.

Comment: don't use apis explore to get the refresh token use your own code please and let me know if you are still having a problem

Comment: I'm using https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference to get the refresh tokens. I'm not getting it from the apis explore